# Nice application of dominated convergence theorem

Tags: integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, measurable-functions

Let $\delta \in \mathbb{R}$, $$f(x)=\frac{sin(x^2)}{x}+\frac{\delta x}{1+x}.$$

Show that $$\operatorname{lim_{n\to \infty}} \int_{0}^{a}f(nx)=a\delta$$ for each $a>0.$
I am unable to find integrable bound for the sequence of function $\{f(nx)\}$. And want to apply Dominated convergence theorem.

Comment: Can we find a Bound for $f(nx)$ such that we can interchange limit and integration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$|f(t)|\le t+\delta t\le (1+\delta)a$ if $0 \le t \le a$ and $|f(t)|\le \frac  1 x+\delta\leq (\frac 1 a+\delta)$ if $t >a$. So $|f(t)|\le \max \{(1+\delta)a, (\frac 1 a+\delta)\}$ for all $t$. The constant function $g(t)=\max \{(1+\delta)a, (\frac 1 a+\delta)\}$ is a dominating integrable function for $f(nx)$ on $[0,a]$.

Comment: Thank you ma'am.